# jQuery menu drop down

Tags: jquery, this

I've got a menu and want to make some changes for Safari. Only one `submenu` should be visible once hovered over link.

I think this can be done using $this, but not sure how and where to write it.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function () {
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') === -1) {
    $(".navbar .nav li").hover(function () {
        $('.navbar .nav li ul').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'opacity': '1',
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(".navbar .nav li ul").css("display", "none");
    });
   }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rolandas/hmuhf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Missed to add jQuery library.
2) This is where `this` keyword helps, because each time you are referring class `$('.navbar .nav li ul')` so it is showing for the elements.

```
$(".navbar .nav li").hover(function () {
  $(this).find('ul').css({
      'display': 'block',
      'opacity': '1',
      'visibility': 'visible'
  });
}, function () {
  $(this).find('ul').css("display", "none");
});
```

Try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmuhf/1/)

Comment: @Roland I'm glad I was able to help :)